# Accessing controller helpers in ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to access a helper method in my email templates. The helper is defined in a controller, and is a `:helper_method`. How can I do that? I know how to use helper *files* in ActionMailer, but this is different.

## edit

I don't want to pass the result of the helper into mailer method, since I'd have to do that on every single mail method.

Comment: What do you mean by "the helper is defined in a controller" ? Also maybe give the method definition of helper method you want to access may help us to find the good pattern to use.

Answer (score 2):

Just pass current_user to mailer method. Mailers shouldn't access session variables and your current_user method depends on a session variable. What if you send email as a background process? Who will be the current_user ?

```
MyMailer.hello_email(current_user).deliver 

class MyMailer < ActionMailer::Base 
  def hello_email(user)
    @user = user
  end
end
```

Comment: I agree with your assessment. The helper I'm trying to access doesn't actually query a session param, but rather queries a site-wide scope that would be cumbersome to pass into every single mail method.